# How to pass Authorization token from one webapi to other webapi?

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have configured two `applications` in Azure AD. One is a Web API called `app-A` and another is a Web API called `app-B`.

> how to I generate a token at `app-A` using client credentials token
>   and pass that token to `app-B`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correct you want to forward Authorization token from one Web API service to another Web API?

This is how I did it:

- Create a session context that exists within the request context. This is done by using Unity and `HierarchicalLifetimeManager`.
- Extract all headers from the request at `app-a` and put it into the session context
- Using the `HttpClient` to insert the cookies before calling `app-b`.

If you want to, you could also just extract the token only instead of all cookies.

**SessionContext**

```
public class SessionContext
{
    public string Token { get; private set; }
    public CookieHeaderValue Cookies { get; private set; }
    public void SetToken(string token)
    {
        if(Token != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Token is already set in this session.");

        Token = token;
    }

    public void SetCookies(CookieHeaderValue cookies)
    {
        if (Cookies != null)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Cookies is already set in this session.");
        Cookies = cookies;
    }
}
```

**CookieFetcher**

```
/// <summary>  ActionFilter to extract all cookie and add it to the <see cref="SessionContext"/>. </summary>
public class CookieFetcherAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var cookies = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetCookies().SingleOrDefault();

        if (cookies == null)
            return;

        var sessionContext = actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope().GetService<SessionContext>();
        sessionContext.SetCookies(cookies);
    }
}
```

**Unity config**

```
// Gets a new TokenProvider per request
container.RegisterType<SessionContext>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```

**Client**

```
public class Client
{
    private CookieHeaderValue Cookies => sessionContext.Cookies;

    public Client(SessionContext sessionContext)
    {
        this.sessionContext = sessionContext;
    }

    private HttpClient CreateHttpClient()
    {
        // If cookie/sessionId based authentication is used. 
        if (Cookies != null)
        {
            handler.CookieContainer = ConvertToCookieContainer(Cookies, baseUri.GetRootHostName());
            handler.UseCookies = true;
        }

        var client = new HttpClient(handler, true);
        client.BaseAddress = baseUri;

        return client;
    }

    private static CookieContainer ConvertToCookieContainer(CookieHeaderValue cookies, string cookiePath)
    {
        var container = new CookieContainer();
        foreach (var cookie in cookies.Cookies)
        {
            container.Add(new Cookie(cookie.Name, cookie.Value, "/", cookiePath));
        }
        return container;
    }
}
```