# Understanding OAuth authorization code flow with Angular, ADFS and .NET Web API

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, oauth, adfs

I have a AngularJS Web Application that requests data from API written in .NET Web API.

Now, I have ADFS 3.0 OAuth configured with my client ID and redirect URL(https://www.someredirecturl.index.html) utilizing Authorization Code Grant Flow.

I also have a .NET Web API that returns some values.
For e.g https://www.example.com/showData

1. Whenever, i call the URL, the ADFS Login screen shows up.
2. Then, the browser is redirected to my Redirect_URL with the authorization code. For e.g https://www.someredirecturl.index.html?code=xxxxxxxxx
3. Then, i capture the code and send it to the ADFS server( POST REQUEST ) to get the token.
4. Now, i have the token.

After this step, i should be able to call my API https://www.example.com/showData with Authorization Code: Bearer + token.

But, how does it work without writing anything at the server side.
Do i have to read the headers with key Authorization, extract the token?
What is the best way to do this?

At any point, will i see data on the browser directly, or it will always be called by some program sending headers.

What if www.example.com is a website. and www.example.com/api is a resource endpoint. How to merge the two of them. can user login to www.example.com when he would enter his credentials on ADFS. How to redirect from Redirect_URL with authorization code?

Comment: I am afraid your question is not clear, you have Authorize users and roles in your API, and yes **if you set the Authorization in your API, the controller or action must be called sending headers**

Comment: @VictorHugoTerceros My identity server authorizes Users, I am missing the link between my Identity Server and Resource Server. What do i have to do in my Resource Server to understand the token and return back the data.

Comment: I think I understand, seems similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915533/how-to-pass-authorization-token-from-one-webapi-to-other-webapi

Comment: @VictorHugoTerceros that question deals with a different subject.My concern however is that ADFS is the issuer, not the Web API itself. So, how will the Web API know it is safe to return the data. Do i have to check the token i received on the headers on the Web API code, validate it and then return the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - as per [this](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/verify-access-token).

Basically:

- Check that the JWT is well formed
- Check the signature
- Validate the standard claims
- Check the Client permissions (scopes)

jwt.io has a number of libraries that do this for you.

Comment: Got it. Thanks. What if www.example.com is a website. and www.example.com/api is a resource endpoint. How to merge the two of them. can user login to www.example.com when he would enter his credentials. How to redirect from Redirect_URL with code?

Comment: http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2013/10/25/securing-a-web-api-with-adfs-on-ws2012-r2-got-even-easier/